# Storing Facebook Info in ASP.NET: Session, Cookies or Identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, facebook, single-sign-on

So, simple question:

After the user authorizes my app (OAuth 2.0), i do a call to the Facebook Graph API to fetch their details.

So at this point in time, i have their Facebook ID, an access token for API calls, their email, and some other basic info.

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 3 web application, that uses Forms Authentication and a custom ticket to store extra data.

A lot of examples i've seen has shown storing the info in Session.

Is this wise? Because i'm working on a single-sign-on (e.g users can "sign in" to my website with Facebook Connect), i only really "care" about their Facebook info if they are already logged-in to my website.

With that in mind - i'm wondering if it's worthwhile segreating the info across different persistence mechanisms.

For instance, since the Facebook ID doesn't change, i could store that in the Forms Authentication ticket, and perhaps store the access token in a cookie, with the expiry set to the expiry received in the HTTP response.

How do people go about storing Facebook information in an ASP.NET (MVC - but not specifically limited to) application?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue right now.  Currently, I'm getting the Facebook username (or email) and setting 
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);

Where username is from Facebook.  The issue I'm trying to figure out now is what happens if I already have a member (via Forms Auth) with the same username.

Comment: @Derek - well i use my system's username for the cookie, and i'm currently using a custom principal. So i'm thinking about storing the Facebook ID in the principal, and the access token in a cookie. The rest of the stuff (facebook user details) can be stored in the DB, since i don't need that on every HTTP request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a mix of Session and the Forms Auth ticket.

In the ticket, i store the user's Facebook ID, as this does not change.

However, i also need to store if the user is currently authenticated to Facebook (just a basic flag) and the OAuth token.

It doesn't make sense to store this data in the cookie, because if they logged out of Facebook or the OAuth token expires, i'd then either have to update the cookie or sign them out of Forms Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store facebook info in a session. javascript SDK saves for you a special cookie called fbsr_APP_ID with a signed_request, so you can verify all requests to your server and obtain neccessary info. Most of the API calls you can do from javascript API to facebook.

You can always check on any page of your app if the user is logged in with FB.getLoginStatus
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

If user is not logged in you can use FB.login to login:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Storing info in sessions is not scalability-wise. It takes memory on your server, etc.

hope this helps

EDIT:
Just to add to the above: don't store any info beyond uid and access token in any persistent storage, basic info from graph API "me" for example might be stored in a database. For the needs of UI basic things like name and picture might be constructed within UI with the help of XFBML tags and urls, etc. Javascript API is also responsible to save a cookie with signed_request which might be verified on the server.

Comment: But im not using (nor do i want to) use the JavaScript SDK. It's legacy, you should be using the Graph API and OAuth 2.0.

Comment: And for these calls, you need an access token. You need to store this *somewhere*, otherwise you will not be able to make any API calls. The JavaScript API was actually deprecated (for authentication) 2 days ago.

Comment: you're talking about old javascript SDK, new javascript library is OK to use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: my bad. Your right. But still, i'm using OAuth server-side, not the JavaScript SDK. And i don't want to switch.

Comment: if you're talking about facebook connect - you have to use javascript library i.e. connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js etc. PHP SDK for example uses the cookie I mentioned from the javascript library out of the box.

Comment: That cookie has basic persistant info you need, i.e. uid, locale and access token, if you need more, make a call to graph api "me" either server-side or client-side, don't store that info in either persistant storage.

Comment: "if you're talking about facebook connect - you have to use javascript library". Um, no you don't. I have a regular link called "Connect to Facebook" which does a HTTP GET to the oauth page, then comes back to my domain. This is all server-side, no JavaScript.

Comment: I understand but this is not facebook-connect then. So you don't use any javascript there, no dialogs, no iframe resize, no ajax?

Comment: Correct. I guess there;s an ambigiouty about the term "facebook connect".

Answer (score 0):

You can put whatever you want in `userData`:

```
 var ticket = FormsAuthenticationTicket(int version, string name, DateTime issueDate,
    DateTime expiration, bool isPersistent, string userData, string cookiePath);
```

Comment: Yes - i know, as i said in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a little class to hold the Facebook properties you need, you can serialize it to a Base64 encoded string and store that in the Roles property of the FormsAuthentication Ticket (the cookie).

Comment: The thing i was thinking though, is that i also use the access token/id to determine "if this user is signed into facebook". This flag is used all over the place. So if i logout of Facebook, i then need to clear the forms auth ticket (e.g "re"-sign in). Which is a bit silly, wouldn't you agree?